# Running an EXE from Java

Tags: java, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I need to run an executable file from Java and have it open in a separate window. When I open the file without using Java, it works perfectly, but nothing seems to happen when I try to open it using Java code. I have tried using getRuntime and ProcessBuilder. The lines I used are below.

ProcessBuiler:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\Louis Windows\\workspace\\Py2exetest\\dist\\test.exe");
Process p = pb.start();
```

getRuntime:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Louis Windows\\workspace\\Py2exetest\\dist\\test.exe", null, new File("C:\\Users\\Louis Windows\\workspace\\Py2exetest\\dist\\"));
```

Both seemed to give the same result (nothing). Any ideas how I can make test.exe open in a new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows, you could try using cmd.exe to launch the process.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "C:\\Users\\Louis Windows\\workspace\\Py2exetest\\dist\\test.exe");
pb.start();
```

Comment: I just tried that and it launched the command prompt, but didn't seem to execute anything. Any ideas how I can ensure it does?

Comment: I tried your idea of using the command prompt and tried to set the current directory to the appropriate folder and then starting the exe file, but for some reason it wouldn't let me execute 2 cmd commands at once. Code:
`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "cd", "dist", "&&","start","test.exe");
      Process p = pb.start();`

Comment: Managed to make it work by doing it all in one command: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start dist\\test.exe");`. Thanks a lot @Sepehr !!!